# Странное поведение TextView

Tags: getview, android, textview

Доброго времени суток.
Есть база, данные из нее выводятся в ListView, есть Layout-ресурс из трех TextView и данные выводятся в виде таблицы.
Столкнулся с тем, что если вывожу в textview только цифры то теряются разметка и форматирование, если вывожу текст, или текст и цифры все нормально.  Всевозможные танцы с бубном результата не принесли, никогда с подобным не сталкивался, даже не представляю как гуглить подобную  неожиданность, если кто то с подобным сталкивался заранее спасибо.

---

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="45dp"
          android:weightSum="13" android:gravity="center_vertical">

<TextView
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@drawable/tvborder"
        android:id="@+id/tvIterator"/>
<TextView
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:background="@drawable/tvborder"
        android:id="@+id/tvNameC"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>
<TextView
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:background="@drawable/tvborder"
        android:id="@+id/tvDate"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
        textView.setText(""+ (position+1 ) );
        textView1.setText(item.getName() );
        textView2.setText( ControllerCompetitions.readById(context, item.getId_competitional() ).getName() );
```

getName() в обоих случаях возвращает строки

---

public class SprintAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
Context context;
List<ContractDB.Sprint> values;
int select;

/**
 *
 * @param context
 * @param objects
 */
public SprintAdapter(Context context,  List objects, int select) {
    super(context, R.layout.item_competitions, objects);
    values = objects;
    this.context = context;
    Log.d("log", "constructor ");
    this.select = select;

}

public void setSelect(int select){
    this.select = select;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_competitions, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvIterator);
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvNameC);
    TextView textView2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
    try {
        ContractDB.Sprint item = values.get(position );

        textView.setText(""+ (position+1 ) );
        textView1.setText(item.getName() );
        textView2.setText( ControllerCompetitions.readById(context, item.getId_competitional() ).getName() );

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } if(position%2 == 0){
        textView.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tvborder_color));
        textView1.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tvborder_color));
        textView2.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tvborder_color));

    }
    if(position == select){
        textView.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tvborder_select));
        textView1.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tvborder_select));
        textView2.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tvborder_select));
    }

    return rowView;
   }
}
```

Comment: покажи еще код самого адаптера

Comment: хм, почему мапишь на parent, а не на convertview? почитай про паттерн viewholdet

Comment: спасибо, попробую. Почему parent ? - хмм, действительно ... как то так сложилось, еще когда начинал разбираться с адаптерами попался такой пример ... надо будет поподробней разобраться ) еще раз спасибо, буду исправлять пробелы

Answer (score 1):

Лучше бы ты показал код и разметку, но попробую быть экстрасенсом - вероятней всего ты передаешь в `TextView` `int`-значения, это понимается как `id` ресурса, который  не находится, потому вероятней всего поможет приведение к `String`